# Slow texture fetch in fragment shader using Vulkan

Tags: glsl, vulkan, ssao

I am doing a SSAO shader with a kernel size of 64.

SSAO fragment shader:

```
const int kernelSize = 64;
for (int i = 0; i < kernelSize; i++) {
        //Get sample position
        vec3 s = tbn * ubo.kernel[i].xyz;
        s = s * radius + origin;
        vec4 offset = vec4(s, 1.0);
        offset = ubo.projection * offset;
        offset.xy /= offset.w;
        offset.xy = offset.xy * 0.5 + 0.5;
        float sampleDepth = texture(samplerposition, offset.xy).z;
        float rangeCheck = abs(origin.z - sampleDepth) < radius ? 1.0 : 0.0;
        occlusion += (sampleDepth >= s.z ? 1.0 : 0.0) * rangeCheck;
    }
```

The samplerposition texture has the format `VK_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_SFLOAT` and is uploaded with the flag `VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT`.

Im using a laptop with a nvidia K1100M graphic card. If I run the code in renderdoc, this shader takes **114 ms**. And if I change the `kernelSize` to 1, it takes **1 ms**.

Is this texture fetch time normal? Or can it be that I have set up something wrong somewhere?

Like the layout transition did not go through, so the texture is in `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL` instead of `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL`.

Comment: Why do you think this is vulkan specific? You simply do a lot of work! I think the fact that running the loop 64x vs. 1x costs more than 64x is because on 1x the compiler will get rid of the loop. Try changing resolution. Does time change linear with the number of pixels? If yes, you are just saturating the GPU. Optimize the loop!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GPU memory relies on heavy cache usage, which is very limited if fragments close to each other do not sample texels that are next to each other - also known as a lack of spatial coherence. I would expect about 10x slowdowns or more on random access to a texture versus linear, coherent access. SSAO is very prone to this when used with large radii.

I recommend using smaller radii and optimizing the texture accesses. You're sampling 4 16 bit floats, but you're only using one. Blitting the depth to a separate 16 bit depth only image should give you an easy 4x speedup.

Comment: It'd probably be better to not write the position at all. Just reconstruct it as needed from the depth and fragment coord; that's how most deferred renderers work.

Comment: @NicolBolas Interesting, I was just searching for it, wonder why I never read about that before. It will not help for SSAO though

Comment: @Samantha: Sure it will. Rather than fetching 64 bytes, you only fetch 32 bytes (the depth buffer value).

Comment: @NicolBolas yes indeed, but this is the way people normally do it, iterate 32-64 times in pixel shaderf or ssao, it will still take a lot of time because you will still get cache misses

Comment: @Samantha: I mean each fetch only accesses 32-bytes of data. Reducing the size of the data you retrieve improves cache coherency and overall is helpful to texture access performance.

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating the Texture coordinates on the fragment shader which means you are not allowing the GPU to pre-fetch the textures. Better calculate all texture coordinates on the Vertex shader and pass it as varying.

Updated:
I would suggest adding some advanced tricks on SSAO than trying to purely calculate the AO map. 
1. You can render a much smaller AO Map and upscale it by adding some blur filter. This will give much better results.
2. If you are trying to do realtime rendering, then AO Map does not need to be calculated every frame. You can fake it based on your setup.

Disclaimer: I do a lot of OpenGL ES based shaders, and my knowledge is mostly limited to Mobile Platforms.

Comment: So 114 ms sounds like a normal time if it has not been pre-fetch by the shader?

Comment: By saying 114ms do you mean per fragment? or for the entire frame?

Comment: for the SSAO shader, the whole draw call, its 114ms / 64 = 17 ms per texel fetch on 1024x1024 window.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, dependent texture reads are indeed only an issue on mobile platforms. It's still a good idea on all platforms to move calculations from fragment shader to the vertex shader whenever you can, though.

Comment: @codetiger It goes much faster when I am pre-calculating the coordinates in the vertex shader, but I cant really do it in this case, I will not get the same interpolated values.

Comment: @Samantha Can you explain why you are not able to pre-calculate the coordinates in vertex shaders?

Comment: @codetiger: Probably because there are 64 of them. Most GPUs don't let the VS shove that much data at the FS.